# My apps web view doesnt shrink when opening virtual keyboard?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a app in which i have set height and width in % , there is a form page with 20 input fields , but the input field below the keyboard are not displayed as keyboard is above them , the page doesnt shrink as it was supposed to , what could be the sollution , i tried everything but nothing helps , changing config.xml as

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

and making android manifest change like this -->

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
```

also this -->

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
```

i dint get the desired result so please help if anyone have the solution or this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your application won't shrink, as the keyboard will open OVER the app.  I make sure that the page is scrollable (don't make it position: absolute and use stopPropagation on touch events for example), and when the keyboard opens it will scroll the content appropriately.

Comment: i have two divs as position :fixed and rest is a scrolable content , so what should i do to make it shrink when keyboard appears ?

Comment: You really would need to consider repositioning content on page, or not using position:fixed. Can you move input upward? Could you use a div which itself appears above the keyboard vertically. 

One of the key issues for web app developers is to have the customer experience as paramount and designing around that in the context of the fragmentation and multitude if devices in the Android universe.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but your answer is wrong.  The keyboard only pops up OVER the app when the activity's `windowSoftInputMode` is set to `adjustPan`.  When the value is set to `adjustResize`, the viewport will shrink and the keyboard will **not** overlay the content.  Please update your answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use scrollViews, take a look at this:

http://davidwparker.com/2011/08/30/android-how-to-float-a-row-above-keyboard/

Using this you can put your submit button over the keyboard or user can scroll to the button to submit.

Comment: this is a phonegap application i am talking about , the layout is built using HTML CSS and javascript , web technologies , so do you have something on that ? as you have given a answer for a native app.